# Записать все содержимое html-таблицы  в таблицу MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как записать все содержимое `<table>` в таблицу MySQL?

Есть табличка, к которой по функционалу могут добавляться строки с данными. Потом по клику на гипотетическую кнопку все данные должны записаться в таблицу MySQL. И разместиться там в соответствии с размещением в `table`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, решение.

Спасибо =)

P.S. Желательно, чтобы все происходило через AJAX.

Comment: Таблица в базе данных уже есть или ее нужно каждый раз открывать динамично в соответсвии с названиями столбцов? Расположение столбцов в таблице всегда одинаковое?

Comment: Таблица есть. Количество столбцов постоянно. Будет различным только число строк.

Comment: Тогда нужно бежать по всем строчкам таблицы, вынимать все что есть внутри ячейки и составлять по ходу стринг в формате CSV. Потом просто передавать этот стринг на сервер, где он его будет парсить как CSV и уже вписывать все базу данных.

Comment: а можно пример, как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то наподобие:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var csv = '',
                    temp_array = [];

                // бежим по всем строчкам в таблице
                $("table > tbody > tr").each(function(i,e){

                    // внутри каждой строчки находим все ячейки и бежим по ним
                    $(e).find("td").each(function(x,element){

                        // добавляем содержимое кадой ячейки во временный массив 
                        temp_array.push($(element).text());
                    });

                    // преобразуем временный массив в стринг с разделительной запятой и в конце добавляем перенос строки и возврат каретки
                    csv += temp_array.join(",") + '\r\n';

                    // стираем все из временного массива
                    temp_array.length = 0;
                    temp_array = [];
                });

                // посылаем на сервер полученный CSV стринг
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: url,
                    data: {param : csv},
                    success: function(result) {
                        // делаем что нибудь с полученными с сервера данными
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                    <th>Column 3</th>
                    <th>Column 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>6</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>8</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Остается только на сервере получить эти данные, пропарсить CSV и внести в базу данных результаты.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться=)

Comment: думаю что пустое значение если оно есть в ячейках тоже нужно сохранять, т.к. может сбиться значение колонки - если первые 3 значения ячеек из 4х являются пустыми, то при данном алгоритме, занчение 4й ячеки запишется на первое место

Comment: дело в том, что пустых значений быть не может, т.к. таблица создается из формы. заполнили данные-записали в строку таблицы. а уж потом происходит отправка.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что не стоит использовать CSV. Для автора топика будет легче сделать все через JSON. Из таблицы получать прям строками в JSON и передавать, а потом парсить и забрасывать в базу. При надобности вообще Json объекты можно сразу в базу кидать, без парсинга. Потом их соответственно и легко будет назад вставлять в табличку. Но это как уже будет удобнее.

Comment: Пример, пожалуйста) Я сейчас с миру по нитке собираю по данной теме =)